# SharePoint Checkin file - Method or data member not found

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

When running the below VBA script, macro checkin, I am getting the error 'Method or Data Member Not Found. Can someone please help identify the issue?

```
Sub checkin()
    Dim docCheckIn As String
    docCheckIn = "File Location and Name"
    Call UseCheckIn(docCheckIn)
End Sub
Sub UseCheckIn(docCheckIn As String)
    docCheckIn = "File Location and Name"
     ' Determine if workbook can be checked in.
    If Workbooks.CanCheckIn(docCheckIn) = True Then
        Workbooks.checkin docCheckIn
    Else
        MsgBox "Unable to check in this document at this time."
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `Workbooks.CanCheckIn(docCheckIn) = True` is the problem. What are you trying to achieve? What's `CanCheckIn` meant to be?

/edit:
`Workbooks(docCheckIn).CanCheckIn` will work but the `docCheckIn` must be a workbook name, not full path. Alternatively set the workbook as object using your `docCheckIn` path and use `WbObj.CanCheckIn`

/edit2:
bear in mind that the `Workbooks.checkin docCheckIn` will have to be changed the same way to either `Workbooks("workbookname.xls").checkin` or `WbObj.checkin`

To set workbook object:

```
Set WbObj = Workbooks("workbookname.xls") 'if it's open

Set WbObj = Workbooks.Open(docCheckIn)    'if it isn't open
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the reply. The file is currently checked out. I am trying to check that it is available to be checked in and if so, to check the file back in. I have a very similar macro to check the file out and that one is working OK

Comment: What is the 'CanCheckIn'?

Comment: method to check if the file can be checked in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.cancheckin

Comment: Aw I admit I didn't know it! I think what you missed is the workbook name in this line, I have edited my response - let me know if it worked

Comment: No prob, please remember to mark this as correct answer :)